# I'm having trouble setting up Ros master-slave

Tags: ros, master-slave

I'm still learning ROS and I'm not good. I have a question. I ran roscore on the master and ran the turtle node on the slave computer and checked if the topic was posted correctly. The matters were true for the master and the slave. So I could see the threads posted on the host and the auxiliary computer. However, when I want to send a speed command from the host, the slave does not receive the commands sent by the master. (My Ros version is Kinetic) main ip: 192.168.137.aaa , slave ip: 192.168.137.bbb. I made the ROS master-slave setting as follows:

Master Computer (~/.bashrc);

```
export ROS_IP = 192.168.137.aaa
export ROS_MASTER_URI = http: //192.168.137.aaa: 11311 
source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bas
echo "ROS_IP:" $ ROS_IP
echo "ROS_MASTER_URI:" $ ROS_MASTER_URI
```

Slave Computer (~/.bashrc);

```
export ROS_IP = 192.168.137.bbb
export ROS_MASTER_URI = http: //192.168.137.aaa: 11311
source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash
echo "ROS_IP:" $ ROS_IP
echo "ROS_MASTER_URI:" $ ROS_MASTER_URI
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi this problem solved for me as follows:
i edited sudo nano ~/.bashrc for master and slave computer:
Master computer:

```
export ROS_IP = 192.168.137.aaa
export ROS_MASTER_URI = http: //192.168.137.aaa: 11311
source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash
```

Slave Computer:

```
export ROS_IP = 192.168.137.bbb
export ROS_MASTER_URI = http: //192.168.137.aaa: 11311
source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash
```

1. I ran Roscore in Master computer than ran turtlesim_node in slave computer.
2. I ran  `rosrun turtlesim turtle_teleop_key` in Master Computer and controlled the slave computer with the keyboard.
   Remember to reboot after export and make sure you are running the correct nodes. One of my mistakes was running the wrong control code.